# How can I decrypt a file with gpg to screen and not write to disk?

Tags: gnupg, decryption

I currently use a script to decrypt a file, but it writes it to disk. I then use wipe to clear it. Is there  a way to write it to screen so it never writes it to disk?

I use the command `$ echo PASSWORD | gpg file.txt.gpg` and it creates a `file.txt`. Then I use wipe to erase the file. Can I extract it to my screen or tmp file system and use more/less to view it?

I know I can create a script to build a tmp file system, then decrypt to it, then view it under `/tmp/ramdisk`. I could just delete the `tmp/ramdisk`, but I was sure there was a program or a method to view it one time only to tmp ram system.

Answer (score 3):

By default, `gpg -d` does not write to disk. It just goes to stdout. You can then pipe that to your viewer of choice:

`gpg -d file.txt.gpg | less`

Or for vim, [disable all of vim's temp file features](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6177/the-simplest-way-to-start-vim-in-private-mode). Then

`gpg -d file.txt.gpg | vim -`

Answer (score 1):

All you need is the `-d` option to `gpg`:

```
gpg -d file.txt.gpg
```

Comment: How can you pass it to a non-caching viewer like /bin/less ?

Comment: This will not show the output on a terminal.